# In Gridview RowDeleted event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to use the RowDeleted event to try and reset the data in a  dropdown list in the FooterControl.  I added the event to the markup in the Gridview and put a breakpoint in the event but it is not fired.

I read in another post that RowDeleted requires the datasource to the grid to use a DataSourceID and the .DataSource.  I am binding to the grids using DataTables so I believe I have to use the .DataSource property and not the DataSourceID.

This is my markup:

```
<div id="DelegateGridWrapper">
    <asp:GridView ID="DelegateInfoGridView" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Caption="Delegate Information" 
        CaptionAlign="Top" CssClass="grid" RowStyle-Wrap="true" 
        HorizontalAlign="Left" ShowFooter="true" 
        AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"  ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" onrowediting="DelegateInfoGridView_RowEditing" 
        onrowcancelingedit="DelegateInfoGridView_RowCancelingEdit" onrowdeleting="DelegateInfoGridView_RowDeleting" 
        onrowupdating="DelegateInfoGridView_RowUpdating" 
        ondatabound="DelegateInfoGridView_DataBound" 
        onrowcommand="DelegateInfoGridView_RowCommand" 
        onrowdeleted="DelegateInfoGridView_RowDeleted">
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recipient ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="deligvLblRecipientID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipientID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delegate" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="deligvLblRecipientName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RecipientName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLRecipientName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                        data-placeholder="Choose delegate…" class="chosen-single">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active"> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="deligvLblActive" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>         
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLActive" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLActiveInsert" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>                         
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="deligvEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" 
                                Text="Edit" CssClass="gridActionbutton">
                    </asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="deligvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                                Text="Delete" CssClass="gridActionbutton"  OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Delegate Information?')" >
                    </asp:Button>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="deligvUpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" 
                                    Text="Update" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="deligvCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                    Text="Cancel" CssClass="gridActionbutton"></asp:Button>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="deligvAddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Delegate" Width="90%" CausesValidation="false" 
                                CssClass="gridActionbutton">
                    </asp:Button>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <tr>
                <th>Recipient ID</th>
                <th>Delegate</th>
                <th>Active</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;">
                    No Delegates were found for you. Delegates can be added by clicking the 'Add Delegate' Button.
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLRecipientName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                        data-placeholder="Choose delegate…" class="chosen-single">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="deligvDDLActiveInsert" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <asp:Button ID="deligvAddButtonEmpty" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Delegate" Width="90%" CausesValidation="false" 
                        CssClass="gridActionbutton">
                    </asp:Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
     </asp:GridView>
```

This is how I bind to the grid:

```
private void populateDelegateInfoGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            m_strUserID = CommonMethods.ParseUserID(User.Identity.Name);
            m_strXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetUserDelegates(m_strUserID);
            m_dtUserDelegates = CommonMethods.ParseXML(m_strXmlTableData);
            DelegateInfoGridView.DataSource = m_dtUserDelegates;
            DelegateInfoGridView.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TO DO: Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

This is my RowDelete event:

```
protected void DelegateInfoGridView_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            m_strUserID = CommonMethods.ParseUserID(User.Identity.Name);

            //Get the Footer controls that have the new entry data
            Control tFooterControls = getFooterControls(DelegateInfoGridView);
            DropDownList tddlRecipientNames = tFooterControls.FindControl("deligvDDLRecipientName") as DropDownList;
            m_strXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetAllPossibleDelegates(m_strUserID);
            DataTable tdtAllDelegates = CommonMethods.ParseXML(m_strXmlTableData);
            tddlRecipientNames.DataSource = tdtAllDelegates;
            tddlRecipientNames.DataTextField = "RecipientName";
            tddlRecipientNames.DataValueField = "RecipientID";
            tddlRecipientNames.DataBind();
            tddlRecipientNames.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select...", "0"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TO DO: Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

How can I get the RowDeleted event to fire?

**UPDATE**

RowDeleting event...

```
 protected void DelegateInfoGridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)DelegateInfoGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                int tiRecipientID = Convert.ToInt32((row.FindControl("deligvLblRecipientID") as Label).Text);
                m_strUserID = CommonMethods.ParseUserID(User.Identity.Name);

                m_pagingClient.DeleteDelegateInformation(m_strUserID, tiRecipientID);

                populateDelegateInfoGrid();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TO DO: Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
            }
        }
```

Comment: The RowDeleted event fires up only after a row has been deleted. You need to make sure that you are handling the deleting of a row in your RowCommand event. You button has the CommandName "Delete". Catch that in the RowCommand event with e.CommandName and execute the code to delete the row.

Comment: I use the event 'RowDeleting' to handle the deleting of the row.  Does this need to be changed to the RowCommand event?  I added the RowDeleting event above.  Does the RowDeleting event fire before or after the RowCommand event?

Comment: You have placed your Delete button in a TemplateField. The RowDeleting event maty not fire, but the RowCommand will definitely fire.

Comment: The RowDeleting event has always fired.  The problem is with the RowDeleted event.  From MS documentation is states that if you have a 'Delete' command, you should use the events RowDeleting and/or RowDeleted.  Do I put my RowDeleting code within the RowCommand - 'Delete'?  Or do I need both RowDeleting and RowCommand - Delete?

Comment: I usually use RowCommand only. example:  if (e.CommandName == "Delete") { //code for delete }

Comment: I deleted the RowDeleting command in the markup and commented out the method in the code-behind but I get the error that 'RowDeleting' event not found.  Is there somewhere else that I need to delete this event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73947/discussion-between-kami-and-gloria-santin).

Comment: remove onRowDeleting from your GridView in the aspx.

Comment: I did and it still thinks it is there.  For now, I just commented out the code within the RowDeleting method to get it to run.  It runs but the RowDeleted event is still not firing!

Comment: Try using the DataKeyNames property

Comment: Here is the MSDN example for deleting from GridView. [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleted(v=vs.110).aspx]

Comment: That link displayed 'content not found'  What is the DataKeyNames property for? I am not having trouble deleting a row from the Grid.  My problem is populating the dropdown in the FooterControl when there are no items in the grid.  Using DataBound, gets the data and binds the data to the dropdown but it does not show.  I was told that binding the dropdown AFTER the row is deleted might fix the problem.  But the RowDeleted event will not fire.

Comment: I found my problem.  IT was not in the row deleting but when I identify when the FooterControl is null or not.  Apparently, after you delete all of the rows in a grid the FooterControl is not null yet the grid is empty.  I have to research how to get the Footer control then.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like the RowDeleted event is only fired when the *GridView* deletes the row using an asp data source.  Since you're binding your grid programatically in the code-behind, it's not the grid that's deleting the row, but you, so the RowDeleted even is never fired by the grid.